# eRe is a division ring implies eR is a minimal ideal

Tags: ring-theory

**Problem:
Let $ R $ be a semi-prime ring and $ e $ be an idempotent. If $ eRe $ is a division ring, then $ eR $ is a minimal ideal of $ R $.**

sol:

Let $ p $ be a non-zero right ideal which is contained in $ eR $.
    Since $ R $ is semi-prime, we have that $ p^2 \neq 0 $ and there
    exists $ x \in p $ such that $ xe \neq 0 $.

Note that $ x $ is also in $ eR $. This means $ x=er $ for some $ r
        \in R $. As the result, $ ere=xe \neq 0 $. Because $ eRe $ is a
        division ring, we know that there is an inverse of it. Precisely, $
        (ere)(eae)=e $ for some $ a \in R $. However, $ e=(xe)(eae) \in xR
        \subseteq pR \subseteq p $, this forces $ eR \subseteq p $ and so $
        p=eR $, as desired.

I have two question about the proof. First, I don't know why we can find an element of $ p $ so that $ xe $ is non-zero. Second, I can't see that $ (xe)(ear) \in xR $ is true. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If $xe=0$ for all $x\in p$, then $pe=0$ so $0=peR\supseteq p^2$.

Since $(xe)(ear)=x(eear)$, it's in $xR$.